# How to dynamically manipulate number of video element in HTML with button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new in HTML/CSS/JAVASCRIPT and I'm designing a CCTV dashboard for my school.

Please forgive me if this happens to be a novice question, I have been looking for answers for 2 days straight but no luck...

In total we have 9 CCTV scenes that need to be display but I would like my dashboard to be able to present the videos in 3 different format, which is 1x1, 2x2, and 3x3.

[image]

This is my design (please forgive my peculiar design :) ), and as you can see I have a drop down button floating right at a div together with the title "Videos".

This is the code for my drop down button.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">
            <!-- <h4>Camera</h4> -->
            <b class="caret"></b>
        </button>
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">1x1</a>
            <a href="#">2x2</a>
            <a href="#">3x3</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You guys have probably get the idea by now.... I am thinking of using javascript and each button item would passes an assigned parameter to a functions that would dynamically update the video layout.

When the user selects 1x1, then I'd like the html video tag to expands its width and height and occupy the entire div. Same goes to 2x2 and 3x3.

This is the snippet for my videos.

```
<div style="padding: 0 0 0 12px;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <video id="video1" width="360" controls style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
                <source src="./assets/samples/trailer.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
            </video>
            <video id="video1" width="360" controls style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
                <source src="./assets/samples/trailer.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
            </video>
            <video id="video1" width="360" controls style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
                <source src="./assets/samples/trailer.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
            </video>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <video id="video1" width="360" controls style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
                <source src="./assets/samples/trailer.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
            </video>
            <video id="video1" width="360" controls style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
                <source src="./assets/samples/trailer.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
            </video>
            <video id="video1" width="360" controls style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
                <source src="./assets/samples/trailer.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
            </video>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <video id="video1" width="360" controls style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
                <source src="./assets/samples/trailer.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
            </video>
            <video id="video1" width="360" controls style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
                <source src="./assets/samples/trailer.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
            </video>
            <video id="video1" width="360" controls style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
                <source src="./assets/samples/trailer.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
            </video>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your HTML so far, but I don't see any attempt at the JavaScript yourself, or a "problem" to work off of (eg, "It gives an error!"). Stack Overflow usually prefers people to make an attempt at the problem themselves (using the internet's vast JavaScript-learning resources) and then we can help if you can show us a problem you can't figure out. Your general goal is "On dropdown change, loop through all video elements and change their size depending on the new value"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use relative width's with the video tags.

for example, you need 3 classes:

```
.videocontrol { float:left; display: block; }
.width1 { width: 100%; }
.width2 { width: 50%; }
.width3 { width: 33.3%; }
```

and then your video elements:

```
<div class="video-container">
    <video class="videocontrol width3" ..></video>
    <video class="videocontrol width3" ..></video>
    <video class="videocontrol width3" ..></video>

    <video class="videocontrol width3" ..></video>
    <video class="videocontrol width3" ..></video>
    <video class="videocontrol width3" ..></video>

    <video class="videocontrol width3" ..></video>
    <video class="videocontrol width3" ..></video>
    <video class="videocontrol width3" ..></video>
</div>
```

your dropdown:

```
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#" onclick="setVideoWidths(1);">1x1</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="setVideoWidths(2);">2x2</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="setVideoWidths(3);">3x3</a>
</div>
```

then a little javascript:

```
function setVideoWidths(videoSize)
{
    $(".videocontrol")
        .removeClass("width1")
        .removeClass("width2")
        .removeClass("width3")
        .addClass("width" + videoSize);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve what you want.

By using jQuery you can give percentage width to your `video` elements based on what the user clicked and achieve what you want easily without changing your html.

Because your links are in ascending order I just get the clicked element's index,I add one because indexing starts from 0 and then divide 100 by it.
And then using jQuery's `attr()` function we can then change all `videos` elements width.

So for first option `1x1` we have 100/1=100% width.For second option `2x2` we have 100/2=50% width ....

```
    $("#myDropdown").on("click","a",function(){ 
     $("video").attr("width",(100/($(this).index()+1))+"%");
    });
```

I also removed the inline paddings you had so the percentage widths could work correctly.

https://jsfiddle.net/6aq6ao14/21/